# How does a non-integrated compact fluorescent lamp work?

Tags: ballast, electronic-ballast

I have some bulbs similar to this one: [Osaga UV-C Lamp 36 W PL-L 2G11](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B007QM4786?ref_=ast_bbp_dp) (I can't find a manufacturer page for it)

Can anyone explain how does such bulb work and what other components I need to make it work ?

**Note:** the fact that this is a UV-C lamp should be irrelevant, based on the comments and some answer attempts.

Comment: The first thing you need is a datasheet rather than a catalogue page. The second thing might be a set of UV goggles.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing is to buy a 36W 2G11-base fixture designed for lighting.

You can also easily find ballasts and sockets online (eg. Osram).

The UVC bulb is electrically the same but lacks the phosphor on the inside of the tube, and UV-transparent quartz is used rather than glass for the tube.
.

UVC light is potentially dangerous to vision and can cause skin cancer so proper precautions are important. When we used these for erasing EPROMs it was always in an enclosed box with an interlock.

Comment: The fact that it works the same as a "normal" bulb is not really helpful when you don't know how a "normal" non-integrated compact fluorescent lamp work. Also, good luck being able to search for a 36W 2G11 fixture.

Comment: @0b13d352 *when you don't know how a "normal" non-integrated compact fluorescent lamp work* and what have **you** done to find that information? Hint: Big Clive talks about fluorescent lamps on his Youtube channel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpRMud6EFtE Also search that channel for more videos on the subject.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie frankly I wonder why I wasted my time even asking, with so many high horses around. You don't know me well enough to just assume I haven't done my due diligence and failed because of lack of familiarity with the subject or maybe I'm just stupid.

Comment: You looked at reference designs for electronic fluorescent ballasts? They’re almost obsolete now so there is info out there. Sam Goldwasser’s repair FAQ from the USENET days probably has some info if you really are up to making a solid state ballast from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

PROBABLY a 36W fluorescent lamp ballast and a related starter will suffice.
Osram know and may trell if asked.

UVC protection for eyes an absolute must.
At a minimum a lamp like that can give you arc eye / snow blindness in well under a minute and potentially in far less than that (10-20 s exposure - maybe less).
**Worse** - it MAY be able to cause retinal detachment.
The "experts" tend to tell you it can't but my wife's experience tells me it may.
While being careful she achieved arc-eyc in both eyes that required bandaged eyes for a week and was VERY painful, and also had a retinal tear which could have progressed to detachment if they had not caught it in time.

THEY said it was unrelated and the other damage was fortunate and allowed them to discover it. I did a lot of reading and what I found suggests that enough solid UV can do this. Our tube was AFAIR 18 watts. She was doing some tests for me while i was in China. She is good at being careful. I think that light may have entered her spectacles at an extreme angle on the edges and refracted into her eye due to the short wavelength. YMMV and may not.